# Speakers in the back not working anymore. Config or Hardware error?

Tags: audio, speakers, seat-leon

I bought a Seat leon like 1 year ago with 6 speakers.
4 Of them being in the cockpit and 2 of them being in the backseat doors.

When I switched into the sound configuration I had the option to change the focus between left and right and back to front.

Today I just noticed I wasn't able anymore to move the focus between back and front, after a bit of investigation I also realized that the speakers in the back doors aren't giving any output anymore.

Is this something I can fix by configuring it myself or is it a known error I have to go to a service station to get it fixed?

Comment: What year was the car manufactured? Are you saying that the option to focus to the back speakers is now gone from the configuration menu? Or that the speakers just do not work? Have you read thru the owner manual regarding the sound system?

Comment: @CharlieRB: The car was manufactured in april of 2016 and handed over in june. And yeah, I'm saying that actually the option to focus to the back speakers is gone from the configuration menu. Before it displayed 4 seats and 5 buttons (4 directions and the center button) Now its just displaying to seats and 3 buttons anymore (left, center and right). This just caused me to check them and I realized both of them are not giving any output.

Comment: I am unable to find an online manual (I am in the USA), so I am unable to find configuration information. Is there more than one type of sounds system option for that car? Which do you have? Have you looked at your owner manual for information? Is there a reset feature in the configuration menu?

Comment: @CharlieRB: there were a standard system with 4 speakers for front (which my configuration menu just seems to assume controll) a 6.1 upgrade (which I purchased) and an theoretical 8 speaker system which doesn't matter for me. I could make an manufacturer reset over the control panel but am too scared yet what actually will be afected by that. I also don't have an online manual for my car and the manual the car was shiped with is in czech, which I'm not able to read.

Comment: I found this site for [Manuals](http://www.seat.com/owners/your-seat/manuals-offline.html). Select your model and download the manual. As far as factory reset, typically they reset every setting to what it was when the car came from the factory.

Comment: Does this car still have a warranty on it? Also, I'm thinking most dealers will have some knowledge of how to operate the sound system. I'd check with them, but this seems to be a configuration issue and not a physical issue. I think the stereo system lost itself somehow.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2: Yeah, there is still the producers warranty running, so I'm not too concerned and I'll just let it being fixed. But still I was wondering. I just did an manufacturer reset yesterday and the option were available again as I knew them... untill I restarted the engine. Also I noticed the back speakers aren't operating anymore at all. (shifting the sound backwards just reduced sound untill it was for full back focus simply like beeing muted.) Consider putting it as answer BTW if you can append a bit on that comment. :)

Comment: Did you get this fixed? I’ve got the same issue with a 2015 Seat Leon estate. Back speakers have just disappeared in setup.

Comment: @Gav: Well, I figured a few things about when this happens. I brought my car to a repair service, and they exchanged parts, and claimed to have figured what was causing the problem, but the problem remained every time. So far I think it is some error with the the control unit of the cars system, My car being from 2015, too just confirms this. So far my observations are, it is never gone for ever, its just sometimes there and sometimes it isn't. Hot temperatures seem to promote this, as in the summer months the speakers barely ever were active, and if I have hot A/C on its rarely detected, too.